# Evaluation of $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin ( \pi \cos(x) )}{x \sin x}$ using a Taylor Approximation

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

> Compute the limit: $$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin ( \pi \cos(x) )}{x \sin (x)}$$
>   using a Taylor approximation

It seems very intuitive for me to use a Taylor Approximation for this kind of a problem, since the values of $x$ get arbitrary small.

**My Approach** (wrong):

$$\cos (x)= 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4) \implies \pi \cos (x)= \pi - \frac{\pi x^2}{2}+ \dots  \\ \sin (x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^6)$$
My problem now is to compute $\sin ( \pi \cos (x)) $. One of my tutors once told me for small values of $x$ I can always use $\sin (x) \sim x$, so I thought that the following must be true as well for small values of $x$: $$\sin (\pi \cos (x))= \sin\left(\pi - \frac{\pi x^2}{2}+ \dots \right) \sim \pi - \frac{\pi x^2}{2}+ \dots$$

Which is indeed very wrong, the correct answer is:
$$\sin (\pi \cos (x))\sim \frac{\pi x^2}{2}\pm O(x^4)$$

While it seems clear to me that my answer cannot be true, *(I did it by naively plugging in the values and obtained the same result as I already had for $\pi \cos (x)$)*, I don't see how the above result is obtained. Could somebody show me how to correctly process in that manner?

**Note**: In class we were not yet introduced to the $O$-Notation. In the book by C.T. Michaels he simply uses dots for the higher terms and says that they can be neglected. I tried to include the $O$-Notation in my question, but only with my intuitive understanding of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've done everything almost right; the problem is that

$$\sin {(\pi - \frac{\pi x^2}{2})} \nsim \pi - \frac{\pi x^2}{2}$$ beacuse the argument of the sin does not goes to zero! (it goes to $\pi$!)

The correct way of doing that is

$$ \sin {(\pi - \frac{\pi x^2}{2})} = \sin {\frac{\pi x^2}{2}} \sim \frac{\pi x^2}{2}$$

(becasue $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin x$); note that this time the argument of the sin actually goes to zero

Comment: Allow me to summarize what you said in my own words, just to make sure I understand it correctly. I did use a Taylor Expansion of $\sin (x)$ around the point $0$ to start. My fallacy was to to plugin a Taylor Polynomial of $ \pi \cos (x)$ that no longer keeps $\sin $ centered at $0$ but at $\pi$. Hence my approach couldn't work out, because it now converges to $\pi$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: basically, yes. You have to find a way, then, to return to something that $\to 0$..When using taylor expansion always check  convergency; for example if $x \to 1$, then $\ln x \sim (x - 1)$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We can avoid Taylor's expansion as follows

As $\sin(\pi-y)=\sin y$

$\sin(\pi\cos x)=\sin\{\pi-\pi\cos x\}=\sin\{\pi(1-\cos x)\}$

Comment: Thanks for your hint, although you show me a way to avoid Taylor expansion (which I am not allowed to for this exercise and in my upcoming exam), you also show me how to obtain the correct result. If $\sin (\pi - x) = \sin (x)$ then it is clear that I will obtain the desired result $\sin (x) \sim \frac{\pi x^2}{2}$. However it still keeps me wondering if I could have obtained the same result if I didn't spot that first.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach failed, because you *aren't* plugging small values into $\sin x$: you're plugging in values near $\pi$.

In order to use that approach, you need to use an identity to transform the problem into one where you *are* plugging something small into $\sin$.

Incidentally, formally, we have (as $x \to 0$):

$$ \sin x = x + O(x^3) $$

And also

$$ (\pi - \frac{\pi}{2} x^2  + O(x^4))^3
 = (\pi + O(x))^3
 = \pi^3 + O(x)$$
so the thing you plugged in gives

$$ \begin{align}\sin(\pi \cos x) &= \sin(\pi - \frac{\pi}{2} x^2  + O(x^4))
\\ &= \pi - \frac{\pi}{2} x^2 + O(x^4) + O(\pi^3 + O(x)) = O(\pi^3)
\end{align}$$
which is a particularly useless approximation.

Comment: I believe to understand this, would it fix the problem if I used a Taylor Approximation near the point $\pi$ and then plugin my evaluation for $\pi \cos (x)$? 
As in my comment below. If I use the identity $\sin(\pi -x)= \sin (x)$ things work out just fine.

Comment: @Spaced: Yep, both ways would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$sin( \pi cos(x) )\approx  \frac {\pi }{2}x^2  -\frac {\pi}{24} x^4 +\frac {\pi -15\pi^3} {720}x^6 +O(x^8) $